# On Logout clear SharedPreferences not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two activities, one LoginActivity and the other ProfileActivity. When the user Logs in successfully the ProfileActivity starts while storing SharedPreferences. So then when the user restarts the app he is automatically logged in again.

But the problem is when the user logs off the SharedPreferences don't clear. Any user that tries to login afterwards is automatically logged in with the stored SharedPreferences.

Logs in properly, logs off properly but doesn't clear the SharedPreferences.

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    View.OnClickListener {

//Defining views
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private AppCompatButton buttonLogin;

//boolean variable to check user is logged in or not
//initially it is false
private boolean loggedIn = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlogin);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    //Initializing views
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    buttonLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    //Adding click listener
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
    loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

    //If we will get true
    if(loggedIn){
        //We will start the Profile Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

//Add back button to go back
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
}

public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
    return true;
}

private void login(){
    //Getting values from edit texts
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Handle login here

                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                            //Adding values to editor
                           editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                           editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.commit();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //You can handle error here if you want
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Adding parameters to request
            params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

            //returning parameter
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Calling the login function
    login();
}
}
```

Then My ProfileActivity where the Logout occurs:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Textview to show currently logged in user
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    //Initializing textview
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    //Fetching email from shared preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "Not Available");

    //Showing the current logged in email to textview
    textView.setText("Welcome " + email);
}


//Add transitions and override back button activity
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
}

public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
    return true;
}

//Logout function
private void logout() {
    //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    //Getting out sharedpreferences
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    //Getting editor
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    //Puting the value false for loggedin
                    editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                    //Putting blank value to email
                    editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "");

                    //Saving the sharedpreferences
                    editor.commit();

                    //Starting login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    //Showing the alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Adding our menu to toolbar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menuLogout) {
        //calling logout method when the logout button is clicked
        logout();
    }
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try clearing all the values in the SharedPreferences? `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` followed by a `commit()/apply()`

Comment: I actually tried `editor.clear(); and editor.apply();` without success, it simple doesn't look like it's clearing the SharedPreferences.

Furthermore, when the SharedPreferences are not clearing during Logout, when trying to log back in any username/password is accepted in the LoginActivity - I assume this is because the SharedPreferences are still in cache?

Comment: Did you confirm that the onClick() function is getting called?

Comment: I'm assuming onClick() is working since my activity changes from ProfileActivity to MainActivty - which it does BTW.

Comment: This is quite a weird thing you're facing. I'll try to examine it more thoroughly and respond to you in a short while.

Comment: The only goddamn difference I can spot in my vs your logout is that I'm using an AsyncTask (because I need to signal to the server that the user logged out), and instead of `editor.commit` I'm using `editor.apply`. Can you see if that's precipitating factor?

Comment: Thanks Vucko but even with `editor.apply` no change sin behaviour. The SHaredPreferences don't seem like they get put back to the default values and once logged out the user can then login back with any username and password (even if the credentials don't exist on the server), this is due to the SharedPerferences still being cached I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the context when you're getting the shared preferences and also clearing them would be simplier just like the following:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                //Getting out sharedpreferences
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ProfileActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                //Getting editor
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
                editor.clear();

                //Saving the sharedpreferences
                editor.commit();

                //Starting login activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said, included the context (ProfileActivity) and simply tried using editor.clear(); but that didn't clear the SharedPreferences either, it looks like after I logout I can then login with ANY user/pass, which I assume is a byproduct of SharedPreferences still being in cache.